# Which overlap is stronger, and why?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, bond, orbitals, valence-bond-theory

I was just wondering which overlap is stronger, 2s-3p or 3s-2p? I believe this can probably be explained by involving some sort of mathematics (?) which I haven't used yet.

Edit: Note that 2s-3p refers to the overlap of 2s of one atom and 3p of another atom. Similarly for 3s-2p.

I haven't really come across an example for this case, guessing it's hypothetical. It'd be great if someone could give actual examples too if they exist.

Comment: Could you elaborate, and provide reasoning for the same?

Comment: I don't think it's clear what you are asking. Atomic orbitals on one atom? Well, they don't usually "overlap" (see answer by porphyrin). Maybe you are talking about atomic orbitals on different atoms? Well, then it depends on the example, doesn't it?

Comment: Yeah 2s of one atom, 3p of another. Similarly, 3s of one atom and 2p of another. The interesting part is, I couldn't find examples for such an overlap.

Comment: Maybe this should help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_configuration .  there you can see which atoms have up to their "3p" occupied. If you are interested in one of these examples, give us the two atoms, a bond distance and one might be able to answer that question. Not me though, this is a bit too esoteric for me, I don't want to teach you things that are basically wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An atom's wavefunctions (orbitals) are orthogonal. This follows from the fact that the Hamiltonian is Hermitian, i.e eigenfunctions (wavefunctions) of quantum mechanical operators are orthogonal.  If they are on different atoms then they are not orthogonal and the overlap clearly depends on how far apart the atoms are.

Mathematically orthogonality means that (in one dimension) two wavefunctions $ \psi_i$ and $\psi_j$ satisfy the condition 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \psi_i\psi_jdx =\delta_{ij}$$

where $\delta_{ij} = 1 \text{ if } i=j \text { else } 0$ and is the Kroncker delta. (In this case if $i=j$ then the wavefunctions are also normalised as the product is $1$, this joint condition, orthogonal & normalised  is sometimes called 'orthonormal')

In the case of atomic orbitals there are three quantum number, the principle one *n* and angular ones *l* and *m*. The orthogonality condition is then
$$ \int_0^{\infty}r^2\int_0^{\pi}\sin(\theta) \int_0^{2\pi}\psi^*_{n'l'm'}(r,\theta,\phi)\psi_{nlm}(r,\theta,\phi)~dr ~d\theta ~d\phi=\delta_{nn'}\delta_{ll'}\delta_{mm'}$$

In your examples $n=2$ and $n'=3$ so the orbitals are orthogonal on these grounds alone.

As a check the 2s orbital has the form 
$$ \psi_{2s} = A(2-\sigma)\exp(-\sigma/2) $$
where *A* contains only constants and $\sigma=Zr/a_0$ where *Z* is the atomic number, $a_0$ the Bohr radius and *r* the radial distance. One 3p orbital ($l=1, m=0$) has the form
$$\psi_{3p} = A'\sigma(6-\sigma)\exp(-\sigma/3)\cos(\theta)$$

Integrating the product over the angles $\theta$ which is  the integral $\int_0^{\pi}\cos(\theta)d\theta $. We can see that this integral is zero from a plot of cosine.

Edits:

As the question is now amended, the answer above holds for a single atom, but when there are two atoms then the overlap depends on their separation as the wavefunctions are no longer orthogonal because they have different coordinate origins, one on one atom the other on the other.

The overlap integral is written as
$$S= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \psi_i\psi_j~d\tau$$

where $\tau$ is the set of coordinates. Even in the simplest case of $\ce{H2^+}$ the coordinates needed are prolate spheroidal ones so to give an example it is simplest to use a one dimensional example since the principle is the same but technically more complex in 3D.

Starting with H atom 1s orbitals 
$$ \psi_{1s} = a_0^{-1/2}\exp(-x/a_0)$$

if the atoms a and b are separated by *2R* then the wavefunctions are

$$ \psi_a = a_0^{-1/2}\exp(-|x-R|/a_0) \\
\psi_b = a_0^{-1/2}\exp(-|x+R|/a_0)$$

and the overlap is the integral 
$$ S=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \psi_a\psi_b dx =a_o^{-1}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(-|x-R|/a_0)\exp(-|x+R|/a_0) dx$$

which evaluates to $$S=\frac{(a_0+2R)\exp(-2R/a_0)}{\pi a_0^3}$$

The wavefunctions with $a_0=1$, (and $R=1$ for the first two plots), $\psi_a$ and $ \psi_b$ vs. *x*  overlap $\psi_a.\psi_b$ vs. *x* and overlap integral *S* vs. the atom separation *R* are shown in the figures.

[image: overlaps]

Comment: Could you please explain how this is related to the overlap strength? I'm sorry but I couldn't understand most parts of your argument. A simplified version might help!

Comment: OK, being 'orthogonal' means that here is no overlap at all. The integral of the product of the wavefunctions generates any overlap and as this is zero then no overlap. To see that the product is the overlap draw two curves and multiply them and work out the area, this is the overlap.  Mostly it will not be zero, but try with sine and cosine functions from $0$ to $\pi$.

Comment: Oh! So that really means that the above 2 overlaps, that is, 2s-3p and 3s-2p are not possible at all? Isn't that the conclusion?

Comment: I would assume that the OP means that 2s is on one atom and 3p is on another atom when {s..}he writes 2s-3p, but that should be clarified in the question. Otherwise the question makes not a lot of sense.

Comment: Hmm, yeah you're right. Appropriate edit made. The question remains unanswered though.

Comment: Please note that the question doesn't make a lot more sense now. Maybe it would help if you explained why you are interested in this topic and what conclusions you would draw if provided with an answer. Can't promise anything though, this is very, very vague

Answer (score 0):

The wavefunctions of the electron orbitals of a single atom are orthogonal, which means their total "overlap" is zero. There is a subtle difference (or maybe not so subtle) between saying if you add up the overlap, it sums to zero and saying there is no overlap. For any positive overlap, there is equal negative overlap, meaning for any positive attractive energy between the two, there is equal negative energy between them. As far as *any* two orbitals on two distinct atoms overlapping, it depends on the atoms, their state (energy levels) and the distance between them. For instance, how much sense does it make to ask about the 2s, 2p, 3s, and 3p overlaps for two hydrogen atoms? How about a H and a U atom? (Hint: in *neither* case is there going to be much overlap 2s-3p or 3s-2p, at least, at anywhere near STP. (under conditions like the center of the Sun, or a neutron star, I don't know; you would certainly assume the two are much closer together, but at the same time, many of their electrons will be either ionized or in highly excited states. Too complicated for me to figure out ...